# How to write a recursive while loop for arimethic calculation java parser

Tags: java, parsing, grammar, tokenize, arithmetic-expressions

I have written code for an arithmetic calculation parser with the following grammar

'exp'   ::= term | term + exp | term - exp

term  ::= integer literal

And I have finished the parser for a single term containing only integer literal, however, I cannot achieve the goal of parsing operations in the string equation.

In this application, I was trying to check whether there is a next `token` present by using `Tokenizer.hasNext()` method, and if the `token` is of type `Token.Type.Add` then return a new Exp with the current literal term and operation and the next Exp that is parsed through the `parse()` method. I have defined various classes such as `Token(String token, Type type),Exp(Term) / Exp(Term,Op,Exp),Term(Lit),Lit(int)`

`Tokenizer.takeNext()` will take the next token and remove it from the current tokenizer buffer.
I simply cannot parse operators from the given equations.

```
Parsing equation: 73 + 65 
73=73
Parsing equation: 10 - 4
10=10
Parsing equation: 7 + 9 + 10
7=7
Parsing equation: 5 - 1
5=5
```

This is a general approach that I toke from school lecture and it's not homework problem.  Any help will be appreciated.

```
public class Token {
    public enum Type {Unknown, Lit, Add, Minus, Multiply, Division};
    private String _token = "";
    private Type _type = Type.Unknown;
}
```

```
public enum Operation {
    None (""),
    Add ("+"),
    Sub ("-"),
    Mult ("*"),
    Div ("/");

    String op;
```

```
public class Exp {

    Term _term = null;
    Exp _exp = null;
    Operation _op = null;

    public Exp(Term term) {
        _term = term;
        _op = Operation.None;
    }

    public Exp(Term term, Operation op, Exp exp) {
        _exp = exp;
        _term = term;
        _op = op;
    }
```

```
     public Exp parse(){
        Exp term = parseTerm();
        while(_tokenizer.hasNext()) {
            Token token = _tokenizer.takeNext();
            if(token.type() == Token.Type.Add) {
                Operation op = Operation.Add;
                _tokenizer.next();
                Exp exp = parse();
                term = new Exp(term._term,op,exp);
                }
            }
        return term;
    }

    // <term>   ::= <integer literal>
    public Exp parseTerm(){
        Exp exp = null;
        String Lit = "";
        while(_tokenizer.hasNext()) {
            Token token = _tokenizer.takeNext();
            if(token.type() == Token.Type.Lit)
                Lit+=token.token();
            else
                parse();
            }
        Lit lit = new Lit(Integer.parseInt(Lit));
        Term term = new Term(lit);
        exp = new Exp(term);
        return exp;
        }
```

Comment: In `parseTerm()` you get the next token with `Token token = _tokenizer.takeNext();` but the `parse()` function is called without providing that token to it. So it looks like the next token, which would probably be an operator is being thrown away. Looks like there is missing source.

Comment: @RichardChambers Hi, thank you for commenting, I don't think that is the major problem, but I still add an implementation to take the ```token``` and compared it with the ```Token.Type.Add ```

Comment: What's the difference between `next` and `takeNext` in your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's walk through this for the input `73 + 65`:

You call `parse`, which calls `parseTerm`. `parseTerm` then loops over the tokens. For the first token, it's a literal, so it's added to `Lit` (PS: it's not good style for variable names to start with capital letters). Then the `+` token is read and it goes into the `else`, calling `parse`. Now `parse` calls `parseLit` again, which reads the literal for `65`. The token stream is now empty, so `parseLit` returns. `parse` also returns because the token stream is still empty (note that the loop in `parse` has never been entered).

The value returned from `parse` to `parseLit` is the literal expression `65`, but `parseLit` never actually uses that value. It just calls `parse` and throws the result away.

So now we're back in the first call of `parseLit` and `parse` has just returned. So the token stream is empty and we exit the loop. The content of `Lit` is "73", so that's what's returned from this call to `parseLit`. Now we return to the first call to `parse`, which simply returns the result of `parseLit` because, again, the token stream is empty, so the loop never gets entered.

So what went wrong here is that you consumed all of the input without actually building the tree for the addition. The code that's meant to do that (i.e. the `while` loop in `parse`) never runs because you've already read all the tokens before it ever gets to the loop because of the loop in `parseTerm` and the second call to `parse` (whose result you discard).

Your grammar rule for `term` does not use `exp`, so `parseTerm` shouldn't be calling `parse`. And the rule is also not recursive, so `parseTerm` shouldn't contain a loop. All that `parseTerm` should do is read a single token that should be a literal and then return the appropriate `Exp` object for that.

Comment: Thank you very much for correcting my logical error!